# nagios snmp switch config

Tags: switch, nagios, snmp

I installed Nagios 4.1.1 on Centos7. Already added my Windows 7 PC, and two Windows servers.
Now I wan't to add some switches. My problem is that I have not "`check_snmp`" installed. Already added the addresses into the "`switch.cfg`" and the community strings.

Terminal

[image]

Nagios-web

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the EPEL packages, most of the plugins are split into separate packages so the `check_snmp` plugin is in the `nagios-plugins-snmp` package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir! I installed it, and still don't have the "check_snmp". I got these: check_snmp_int/strorage/process.

Comment: Really? I just checked that package and the only file in it is `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_snmp` which I think is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I don't even have /usr/lib64/nagios.  My plugins is at: /usr/local/nagios/libexec.

Comment: So you haven't installed the package then.

Comment: Ohh, I missed "make install". It worked, Thanks man!